# Firefox keeps crashing in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, crash

I recently installed ubuntu as a replacement for XP. I'm using xubuntu desktop. Mozilla Firefox and other browsers all crash very regularly, with firefox crashing at least 1 in 3 times I open it. This never happened with XP. I looked at the details of the crash firefox provided and it would point to add ons, I have removed ALL add ons and it's still just as bad. Here is the last crash report it gave me:

```
Add-ons: %7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:39.0.3
BuildID: 20150806192122
CrashTime: 1438977157
EMCheckCompatibility: true
Email: jimmydabosh@hotmail.com
FramePoisonBase: 00000000f0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1438954789
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 3192
StartupTime: 1438977154
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 39.0.3
useragent_locale: chrome://global/locale/intl.properties
```

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.

I've tried Chromium and Midori as well as a few other browsers. All crash with great regularity. I have tried uninstalling/reintalling flash, as well as a few other fixes I found on here, but no joy.

Can anyone offer any advice. More info will be provided if needed thank you!!

```
Summary Computer Processor  AMD Athlon(tm) XP 2200+ 
Memory  2031MB (1068MB used) 
Operating System    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Operating System Version Kernel  Linux 3.13.0-61-generic (i686)
Distribution    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
```

Comment: What is your computer? Please add hardware specs.

Comment: Summary
Computer
Processor AMD Athlon(tm) XP 2200+
Memory 2031MB (1068MB used)
Operating System Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Operating System
Version
Kernel Linux 3.13.0-61-generic (i686)
Compiled #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:22:15 UTC 2015
C Library Unknown
Default C Compiler GNU C Compiler version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
Distribution Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: let me know if you need more info :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your CPU does not support SSE2 CPU commands.

New flash plugin for Linux uses that commands and if they are not supported, it crashes.

You can disable flash in Firefox, and it will stop crashing. You can also uninstall flash by running

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
```

There is also an option to install old flash 10.3, but it is not recommended, because it does not get security updates since 2013.

Your CPU is too old for using flash.

But if this does not help, it means that Firefox dropped support of this old CPU and SSE2 is required for some other parts of code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up installing Opera Browser instead and I have had no problems at all.

Comment: I run firefox 41 with similar processor without SSE2 instructions. I think WebKit doesn't support SSE1, but Gecko does.